# Opening links in a new tab and only the new tab

Tags: javascript, html, usability

I need to open a new tab or popup window, and then any other time the original source link is clicked, it updates the already open tab or window. Right now it just keeps opening a new tab and that's not the behavior that's expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify a custom `target` name:

```
<a href="something.html" target="otherpage">Go to some page #1</a>
<a href="something2.html" target="otherpage">Go to some page #2</a>
```

This will "name" the other window/tab and open links with the same `target` in that page, or in a new window/tab if one doesn't already exist. You can achieve the same effect with `window.open` by specifying the name as the second argument.

Comment: @btm1: Could you provide an example page where I can reproduce that, please?